# Threads and Handlers in server socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

How is the `new Handler(clientSocket);` instantiated without an object?. Can somebody give some insight?

```
public class Server1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(15897);
            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                new Handler(clientSocket);

            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("problem here 1");
        }
    }
}

class Handler implements Runnable {

    int red;
    int reads, r;

    Socket clientSocket;

    Handler(Socket s)
    {
        this.clientSocket = s;

        new Thread(this).start();

    }

    public void run(){        
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        try {

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on programmers or code review.

Comment: It seems (to me) that you want to create a new Runnable without a new object, that is not possible in Jav. Also, why does it concern you anyway?

Comment: my code is running fine if i dont write Handler h=new Handler(clientSocket);....and simply write new Handler(clientSocket); so what is the difference nd y is it running perfectly that way also. How is the new Handler(clientSocket); instantiated without an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code Server is made to keep listening the incoming Clients.

```
       Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

`serverSocket.accept()` waits until a connection or a client is found. 
       If client is found then  `accept()` function returns a local socket which is connected to another socket at the client which is given to `clientSocket` in you code.

```
new Handler(clientSocket);
```

Now `clientSocket` is given to `Handler` class  in which you are using `thread` for reading the data given by that `clientSocket`.

The purpose of `thread` here is to  handle each incoming `clientSocket` seprately.

Comment: How is the new Handler(clientSocket); instantiated without an object?

Comment: @CodeEatingMyMind Every thing is written in `Handler`'s constructor. so `new Handler(clientSocket)` will call the constructor of `Handler` class that is `Handler(Socket s)`.

Comment: my code is running fine if i dont write Handler h=new Handler(clientSocket);....and simply write new Handler(clientSocket); so what is the difference nd y is it running perfectly that way also

Comment: @CodeEatingMyMind in both cases you are doing `new Handler(clientSocket)` hence obviously it will call `Handler(Socket s)`. There is no need of creating object  `Handler h`.

Comment: but i m not creating an object in second case

Comment: @CodeEatingMyMind If you do `Handler h = new Handler(clientSocket)` then the right part of `= ` that is `new Handler(clientSocket)` will call the constructor of `Handler` and  initialize the object `h` with some memory. But your code requires only constructor to be called i.e `Handler(Socket s)`. Hence there is no need of creating object but there is need of `new Handler(clientSocket)`. `new` will return some memory, it depends on you whether to catch it or let it go.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incomplete, so it's difficult to say with certainty, but observe that in the Handler's constructor a thread is created and started, which executes `run()`.

Inside that function (and therefore in a separate thread), the input stream is read from the socket into a BufferedReader, from which the first line is obtained.

The thread will block until a line is received over the socket connection.

Because your code is cut off from that point, I can't say what else it does.

Comment: How is the new Handler(clientSocket); instantiated without an object? nd i just posted few lines of my code over here, after this point the code is also using printwriter and normal process of sending the data back to the client is being done..i m just in doubt that How is the new Handler(clientSocket); instantiated without an object?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly does the code do but explaining it to you as per the concept of OOPs, it creates an instance of the Handler class everytime the while loop is executed.

Warning: The while(true) loop is bad code and when the project is run, it will run in an infinite loop.

Comment: Sure it's an infinite loop, like most apps. It blocks on the accept() call.

Comment: How is the " new Handler(clientSocket); instantiated" without an object?